# Is it possible to cover a whole lake by thermocol sheets to prevent it from evaporation?

Tags: evaporation

It has been in news recently that attempts were made to cover a lake with thermocol sheets to stop it from drying.

[A report published by the Central Water Commission on ‘Evaporation control in reservoirs’ did mention about the use of thermocol as a way to control evaporation.](http://www.thequint.com/india/2017/04/22/tn-minister-covers-water-with-thermocol)

Is this possible?

Comment: Well, if you seal the water from the atmosphere it will not evaporate into it, in the same way that water in bottles does not.  So, yes.

Comment: @tfb they aren't making a air tight container around the lake so this is completely different..

Comment: Well, the water won't evaporate where a sheet is since there is no air/water interface. How effective it will be is determined by the percentage of the area covered by sheeting.

Comment: @A.C.A.C. It really is not different.  If you cover the entire surface of the lake by something impermeable, or nearly so, then you are, fairly obviously, going to reduce evaporation to a very large extent.  I'm not sure why you would think otherwise.

Comment: @tfb I don't think otherwise, I know it reduces evaporation but not really the exact physics behind it. I was just pointing out that the example of sealing water in a bottle is different than an open lake with some of the surface covered.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about verifying a claim and not physics.

Comment: If your question would be closed here, maybe https://earthscience.stackexchange.com would be a good place to a retry.